# Python3 dictionary merge based on values

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, merge

I have a dictionary composed of `{key: value}`.

I select a set of keys from this dictionary.

I'd like to build a new dictionary with `{keyA: set of all keys wich have the same value as keyA}`.

I already have a solution: Is there a faster way to do it?

It seems very slow to me, and I imagine I'm not the only one in this case!

```
for key1 in selectedkeys:
    if key1 not in seen:
        seen.add(key1)
        equal[key1] = set([key1])#egual to itself
        for key2 in selectedkeys:
            if key2 not in seen and dico[key1] == dico[key2]:
                equal[key1].add(key2)
        seen.update(equal[key1])
```

Comment: Can you give an example input, output?

Comment: It would probably be faster to build a dictionary that maps `{value: set(keys)}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to create a dictionary that maps `key` to "the set of all keys which have the same value as `key`" for each selected key in a given source dictionary.

Thus, if the source dictionary is:

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 1, 'd': 2, 'e': 3, 'f': 1, 'g': 3)
```

and the selected keys are `a`, `b`, and `e`, the result should be:

```
{'a': {'a', 'c', 'f'}, 'e': {'g', 'e'}, 'b': {'b', 'd'}}
```

One way to achieve this would be to use a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to build a value to key table, and then use that to build the required result from the specified keys:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def value_map(source, keys):
    table = defaultdict(set)
    for key, value in source.items():
        table[value].add(key)
    return {key: table[source[key]] for key in keys}

source = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 1, 'd': 2, 'e': 3, 'f': 1, 'g': 3)

print(value_map(source, ['a', 'b', 'e']))
```

Output:

```
{'a': {'a', 'c', 'f'}, 'e': {'g', 'e'}, 'b': {'b', 'd'}}
```

Comment: this is much faster than what I did. I thought there would be an option using something like Counter libraries which are quit fast!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
>>> a = {1:1, 2:1, 3:2, 4:2}
>>> ret_val = {}
>>> for k, v in a.iteritems():
...     ret_val.setdefault(v, []).append(k)
...
>>> ret_val
{1: [1, 2], 2: [3, 4]}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def convert(d):
    result = {}
    for k, v in d.items():  # or d.iteritems() if using python 2
        if v not in result:
            result[v] = set()
        result[v].add(k)
    return result
```

or just use [`collections.defaultdict(set)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) if you are careful enough not to access any non key later :-)

Answer (score 0):

Since you select a set of keys from the original dictionary. We can modify @Nilesh solution for your purpose.

```
a = {1:1, 2:1, 3:2, 4:2}
keys = [1, 3]  # lets say this is the list of keys
ret_val = {}
for i in keys:
  for k,v  in a.items():
    if a[i]==v:
      ret_val.setdefault(i, []).append(k)
print (ret_val)

{1: [1, 2], 3: [3, 4]}
```

Answer (score 0):

This was sort of stated in the comments by @Patrick Haugh:

```
d=your dictionary
s=set(d.values())
d2={i:[] for i in s}
for k in d:
    d2[d[k]].append(k)
```